# What is the difference of DataFrameWriter.format("hive") and not format?

Tags: apache-spark

Code 1: `df.write.format("hive").saveAsTable()`

Code 2: `df.write.saveAsTable()`

What's the difference of using and not using format("hive")? Is the default format source value of DataFrameWriter is `"hive"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in the way the data gets stored.
In the first case data is stored in text format and uses LazySimpleSerDe
In the second case the data gets stored in parquet format which is the `default` one and it uses ParquetHiveSerDe.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/serde will give you additional information about the Serializer/Deserializer